# Dealing with large XML file

Tags: android, xml, large-files

I am building dictionary application. There is ready XML database of words and translations. It weights 75MB. When I put it in XML folder, Eclipse freeze(get stuck). What suggestions you can give? Maybe convert it to SQLite or json(i heard it is better than XML). What to do? Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file that large, your best bet would be to download it on first run. You cannot place something that large inside the main application (extensions are another story) as Google has a limit of 50mb as the apk max file size. As for sqlite, if you download it and place it in your application, it would be much easier to get information out of it, as you wouldn't have to parse the data each time you want to use it or have the application take a lot of memory.